# Getting value of selected option using ajax and laravel

Tags: php, ajax, json, select, laravel-4

I want to get the value of selected option and pass it to `php` through `ajax` and return back to the document. I'm using `laravel 4`. This is my code:

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control sqaure" id="selectCategory" name="Category">
    <option value="1">Apps/Softwares</option>
    <option value="2">Arts/Graphics</option>
    <option value="3">Business/Marketing</option>
    <option value="4">Domains/Websites</option>
    <option value="5">Media/Entertainment</option>
</select>
```

**AJAX**

```
$('#selectCategory').change(function(event) {
        $.post('fetchSubCategory',{},function(data){
             alert(data);
      });
    });
```

**ROUTE**

```
Route::post('/fetchSubCategory', 'AuctionController@fetchSubCategory');
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function fetchSubCategory(){
        if(Request::ajax()){
            $input = Input::get('Category');
            return json_encode($input);
        }
    }
```

but this method returns "NULL" value when I select an option.
I also tried `$input=Input::only('Category');` but also returns `NULL`.

How could I possibly do this?

Comment: Because you are passing empty value to your `$.post()`? The second parameter is suppose to be the data pass along with your request.

Comment: I also tried putting the value to the second param `var val = $(this).val(); $.post('fetchSubCategory',{val:val},function(data){
             alert(data);` but still returns `NULL`.

Comment: First thing to try, instead of `return json_encode($input)` try to `echo 'Something'` and see from your inspector if that pops up as result. If yes, then try to use `Response::json(compact('input'));` instead of json_encode. See this link: http://laravel.com/docs/responses#special-responses

Comment: please answer this question thanks